# use lodash javascript to full join two-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, join, multidimensional-array, lodash

I have two two-dimensional array.

```
var arr1=[[1,20],[2,30]];
var arr2=[[2,40],[3,50]];
```

This is expected output:

```
[[1,20,null],[2,30,40],[3,null,50]]
```

It is like full join of two data frames. The logic is similar to this pseudo code:

```
df1.join(df2, df1[col_1] == df2[col_1], 'full')
```

but this case is for two-dimensional array. Can lodash do this? If not, how to do it in vanilla javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `lodash` can't do this, but we can:

```
function flatten2d(arr1, arr2) {
  const o1 = _.fromPairs(arr1);
  const o2 = _.fromPairs(arr2);
  const result = [];

  _.forEach(o1, (v, k) => {
    const v2 = o2[k] || null;
    result.push([k|0, v, v2]);
    delete o2[k];
  });

  // at this point, only items non-existing
  // in o1 are left in o2
  _.forEach(o2, (v, k) => {
    result.push([k|0, null, v]);
  });

  return result;
}
```

Testing:

```
flatten2d([[1,20],[2,30]], [[2,40],[3,50]])
```

Result:

```
[[1,20,null], [2,30,40], [3,null,50]]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have duplicate id's in any single array then you can try combine them, and group them using `groupBy` with first element (i.e. the key `0`), and if you have duplicates, anyway I am not sure what exactly output you are looking for! Here is what you can do:

```
    _(arr1.concat(arr2)).groupBy('0').map(v=>
        [v[0][0]].concat(v.length > 1 ? v.map(m=>m[1]) : [v[0][1], null])
    ).value();
```

Here is an working snippet for you:

```js
var arr1=[[1,20],[2,30]];
var arr2=[[2,40],[3,50]];

var res = _(arr1.concat(arr2)).groupBy('0').map(v=>
        [v[0][0]].concat(v.length > 1 ? v.map(m=>m[1]) : [v[0][1],null])
    ).value();
    
 console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your snippet's output is different from the one stated in question.